# Best way to create admin grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent

I want to know the differece of the multiple ways we can create an admin grid in Magento 2.

Some people says that the best way is with the php, because is the best to debug, but i find more responses that are only in xml that it make me think that it's the best way.

In this page i see different [ways](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

and which is the best and what is the difference ?

UPDATE

I see most of people use the uicomponent. It's better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is depend on the requirement

If you need column visibility adjustable using column control and filter in separate dropdown rather than in grid and also search by keyword functionality then **ui-component** is better solution for this.

If you need to show only data without any search and any other operation on grid then simple php grid is better for it.